# Python/Pandas - What is the most efficient way to replace values in specifc columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[2,4,6,8],'c':[2,4,5,6]})
```

and you want to replace specific values in columns 'a' and 'c' (but not 'b'). For example, replacing 2 with 20, and 4 with 40.

The following will not work since it is setting values on a copy of a slice of the DataFrame:

```
df[['a','c']].replace({2:20, 4:40}, inplace=True)
```

A loop will work:

```
for col in ['a','c']:
    df[col].replace({2:20, 4:40},inplace=True)
```

But a loop seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda x: x.map({2: 20, 4: 40}).fillna(x).astype(int))` - as described in the marked dup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation on [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), you can specify a dictionary for each column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [2, 4, 6, 8], 'c': [2, 4, 5, 6]})
lookup =  {col : {2: 20, 4: 40} for col in ['a', 'c']}
df.replace(lookup, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    a  b   c
0   1  2  20
1  20  4  40
2   3  6   5
3  40  8   6
```